# Why is there no csrftoken cookie on Google Chrome and yes on Firefox? - Javascript

Tags: javascript, cookies, csrf, csrf-token

I use a Google Chrome extension that injects code on a site but the 'csrftoken' cookie is required to make operations and requests to the site's Api.

In the javascript file i have:

```
getCookie('csrftoken');

function getCookie(name) {
    const value = `; ${document.cookie}`;
    const parts = value.split(`; ${name}=`);
    if (parts.length === 2) return parts.pop().split(';').shift();
}
```

The strange thing is that on google chrome these are the visible cookies:

```
e2sid=c8l1nddg569yvkxj62iiarlp4r08ufo1; i18next=en-US; _fbp=fb.1.1631121679916.782384057; cookielaw_accepted=1; _lr_uf_-qrlpn5=44189bc6-e54a-49fc-a7ff-68386e3565cc; _lr_tabs_-qrlpn5/e2={"sessionID":0,"recordingID":"4-b10b7425-dadc-4581-9428-49408113de74","lastActivity":1631301023256}; _lr_hb_-qrlpn5/e2={"heartbeat":1631301143709}
```

**There is no csrftoken!**

**But with mozilla firefox is there!**

```
_fbp=hb.1.1615420435388.698735244; csrftoken=P39hGH18QvTbbnbXPQJjvohtsP9rfhWdvym8QFseO2SXhtQk0pRGzIZzsG8R0v4k; cookielaw_accepted=1; i18next=en-US; _lr_tabs_-qrlpn5%2Fe2={%22sessionID%22:0%2C%22recordingID%22:%224-7285fc28-3e2e-4aeb-8868-cb145c375554%22%2C%22lastActivity%22:1631298849357}; _lr_hb_-qrlpn5%2Fe2={%22heartbeat%22:1631298969837}; sessionid=khhmla44khba2hnpkofrljmxblchj6qe; e22sid=kc45umlov487r62zy1qnk5ijglkro1wc; e2sid=wbbcsnxsuffeed2boykowjez9ic24oqh; _lr_uf_-qrlpn5=9524b7b1-4161-4695-9649-ed16ed97fa93
```

How is it possible ? the link is the same but I can't understand why .... the strange thing is that until a few days ago the 'csrftoken' cookie was also present on google chrome and in fact the extension worked perfectly. The site developers have made an update but I don't understand how this could have caused the deletion of the cookie. Is there anything I can do ?

Comment: Google chrome is having too many caching issues these days, you have to upgrade or downgrade your chrome.

Comment: CSRF tokens are inaccessible to JavaScript, by-design. Otherwise XSS attacks could copy the cookie values for making forged requests: https://owasp.org/www-community/HttpOnly

Comment: Also, your `getCookie` function's abuse of template-strings is horrible.

Comment: @Dai but it is a google chrome extension that works when i am on the site so it should take the csrftoken. I am 99% sure otherwise it is not explained how the extension worked until two days ago (before the developers updated the site). The problem is that the "csrftoken" is not visible even in the "developer console". It is visible on firefox but not on google chrome.

Comment: @Borja Do you see any `Set-Cookie` HTTP response headers? Do they have an expiry or cross-site issue?

Comment: the strange thing is that the two cookies are not visible even on Opera. Only visible on firefox and explorer. How is it possible ?